# LESS - Interpolation - Using dynamically generated class name AS A MIXIN itself?

Tags: less, interpolation, mixins

Let's say you want a mixin that accepts a parameter, and uses that parameter to call a different mixin.

```
.text-right {
  text-align: right
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}


// mixin to call one of the above selectors
.text-align( @direction ) {
  .text-@{direction};
}

body {
  .text-align(right);
}

// Unrecognized input on this line
//   .text-@{direction};
```

Trying this results in an Unrecognized Input on the line you try to interpolate the parameter.

[Here's a codepen I made for it.](http://codepen.io/JoshuaSoileau/pen/wgWpWJ)

How can I accept a parameter, and then use that parameter to call a different mixin (where the parameter name is a part of the name of the mixin)??

Comment: This seems to be impossible, but the reverse IS possible: http://codepen.io/mtbottens/pen/rjLJaX

#dinklage

Comment: It depends. If your example is abstract (not just about `text-left-right-whatever` which can be coded much easier), i.e. it's really about reusable mixins then simply *do not* encode mixin parameters into mixin names. Keep parameters as parameters, and with this in mind the whole story indeed should be written exactly in opposite, [for example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/3d95a06e3acd89dbc8916d733f00cb3d).

Comment: Speaking of bounty, no real point in it. The answer is as simple as: "You can't". (Hence the comments recommending to revise your approach which is sort of flawed anyway even if Less has such feature).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Not like this. The relevant line in the LESS source code is in [parser.js](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/49cbe520f6b38b4b8797dcba491501c0c461c7f5/lib/less/parser/parser.js#L780), `mixin.call`- the parser of a mixin call:

```
e = parserInput.$re(/^[#.](?:[\w-]|\\(?:[A-Fa-f0-9]{1,6} ?|[^A-Fa-f0-9]))+/)
```

That is, a valid mixin call may only be named as a valid CSS .class or #id identifier. Everything else is unparseable, and doesn't even get to the variable interpolation stage.

If we relax the requirements of the solution, there is a way. Now, we want a function that takes a part of a class name, and calls a mixin with that class name. If can live with that not being totally dynamic, we can simply implement that function with a number of `when` clauses:

```
.text-align( @direction ) when (@direction=left) {
  .text-left;
}
.text-align( @direction ) when (@direction=center) {
  .text-center;
}
.text-align( @direction ) when (@direction=right) {
  .text-right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the conclusion I came to as well.